# What does the task hierarchy mean in 'docker node ps' output?

Tags: docker

I have a small django app running running in a 3 node docker swarm.  When I run `docker node ps` I get output similar to the following:

```
user@host$ docker node ps $(docker node ls --quiet) --filter desired-state=Running
ID            NAME                    IMAGE                                                  NODE          DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE               ERROR  PORTS
vn2ruaqk503o  proj1_pubsub.1          redis:3.2-alpine                                       proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
vn2ruaqk503o   \_ proj1_pubsub.1      redis:3.2-alpine                                       proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
vn2ruaqk503o   \_ proj1_pubsub.1      redis:3.2-alpine                                       proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
5njupphqr1tu  proj1_db.1              postgres:9.6-alpine                                    proj1-node-3  Running        Running about a minute ago         
ld6w8owhu3ct  proj1_app.1             python:alpine                                          proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
ld6w8owhu3ct   \_ proj1_app.1         python:alpine                                          proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
ld6w8owhu3ct   \_ proj1_app.1         python:alpine                                          proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
iiddlrud5d1x  proj1_proxy.1           nginx:alpine                                           proj1-node-3  Running        Running about a minute ago         
xrm2on457y49  proj1_cache-2.1         memcached:1.4-alpine                                   proj1-node-2  Running        Running about a minute ago         
xrm2on457y49   \_ proj1_cache-2.1     memcached:1.4-alpine                                   proj1-node-2  Running        Running about a minute ago         
lwpgkkk6kkdz  proj1_cache.1           memcached:1.4-alpine                                   proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
lwpgkkk6kkdz   \_ proj1_cache.1       memcached:1.4-alpine                                   proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
lwpgkkk6kkdz   \_ proj1_cache.1       memcached:1.4-alpine                                   proj1-node    Running        Running about a minute ago         
eeco5rl2e4tk  proj1_app.2             python:alpine                                          proj1-node-2  Running        Running about a minute ago         
eeco5rl2e4tk   \_ proj1_app.2         python:alpine                                          proj1-node-2  Running        Running about a minute ago
```

Does anyone know what the task hierarchy in the output means?  What does the fact that proj1_pubsub.1 is listed with two sub items mean?

```
proj1_pubsub.1
\_ proj1_pubsub.1
\_ proj1_pubsub.1
```

The docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ps/#extended-description) does not show an example with this hierarchy information or explain what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "tree" shows tasks (containers) that were replaced, and still available on the node.

When deploying a service, docker monitors the tasks backing the service, and if a task fails, a new task (container) is started to replace the old one. Keeping the old container around allows you to (e.g.) inspect that container to investigate why it failed, or view its logs.

The same happens when you *update* a service (for example update the service to use a newer version of an image), in which case new containers are started with the new image, and the old container is stopped. You can see this in the following example;

```
docker service create --name redis --replicas=2 redis:3.0.6

docker service ps redis

ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
2g423t6ulywl        redis.1             redis:3.0.6         moby                Running             Running 16 seconds ago
8b8yn6opxwaj        redis.2             redis:3.0.6         moby                Running             Running 16 seconds ago
```

Now, updating the image to `redis:3.0.7`;

```
docker service update --image redis:3.0.7 redis

docker service ps redis

ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                    ERROR               PORTS
7dj4opiw1vel        redis.1             redis:3.0.7         moby                Running             Running less than a second ago
2g423t6ulywl         \_ redis.1         redis:3.0.6         moby                Shutdown            Shutdown 8 seconds ago
x15asetswu67        redis.2             redis:3.0.7                             Ready               Pending less than a second ago
8b8yn6opxwaj         \_ redis.2         redis:3.0.6         moby                Shutdown            Running 42 seconds ago
```

The amount of containers "kept around" is configurable through the `--task-history-limit` option on `docker swarm update`, and defaults to 5 (after which older containers are removed)

More in-depth information about "swarm" services can be found in this section of the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/